# WCF service and backup

Tags: wcf

if a WCF service goes down for whatever reason, is it possible that another server hosting the service can take over (kind of like clustering/failover)?

how would you create such a solution? how is it possible? What are the tricks and techniques that can be used in such a situation?

Comment: How are you hosting the service?  Normally you can rely on the host to handle failover etc - are you hosting a singleton service?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I dont know yet just doing a POC type thing with some samples and testing. WAS seems good as it will spin up the service as and when it needs to and if the service errors, it will recycle it/respin the service. But what about for say a console app? how can the service recover from a fault? It wont be a singleton service.

Comment: Just to add more to this, essentially im looking for a self recovering server service. how can one implement this type of behavior to ensure that the service does not go down? if for whatever reason it is unable to come back up, then how can it be re-routed to another available service? (computers will be clustered but I guess this only applies for physical use and not entirely software)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really the solution here was to run an instance per clustered node of the application. it means that if one of the app crashes, the others will still be active.

Alternatively you could have clustered the app and run that.